# Finding probability of normally distributed given mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having trouble finding the correct probabilities for normally distributed data set. The question reads given $\mu=2.117 \; and \; \sigma^2=0.0306$ find the probabilities: (with my solutions)
[image: sol]

Can someone please correct me. Thanks

Comment: Do you know which ones are incorrect?

Comment: Sadly all three are incorrect

Comment: I think should double check your sigma, should be ~0.175 right?

Comment: I think it is correct

Comment: Yes my sigma was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\mu=2.117 \; and \; \sigma^2=0.0306 => \sigma=0.175\\ i)\ P(X>2) = P(Z>\frac{2-2.117}{0.175}) = P(Z < 0.6686) = 0.7486\\ 
ii) \ P(1.9<X<2.1) = P(X<2.1) -P(X<1.9) =0.9821-(1-P(Z<1.24))=0.8746\\
iii)\ P(X<1.5) = P(Z<-3.5257) = 1-P(Z<3.5257)=0$